# How to response in right way from WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I try to write api controller and I got some problem: no response after post message to WebApi. I try googling and I found a few answers, but it doesn't work for me. I don't understand why.

Code for http **post request** (from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client), it's just example from simple mvc controller):

```csh
public ActionResult Test()
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
    return null;
}

static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50984/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP POST
        var gizmo = new ErrorModel
        {
            Key = "2ccab87f5f904d3688a28b1a1fb4269b",
            Name = "HTTP Error 404"
        };
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("exceptionregistration/handle", gizmo);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**WebApi controller:**

```csh
public class HandleController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ErrorModel errorData)
    {
        try
        {
            // some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.error(ex);
            return null;
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
    }
}
```

And this line have never been executed completely (**no response**):

```csh
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("exceptionregistration/handle", gizmo);
```

What's wrong? Why is no result when I wait a response?
Maybe is it a better way to post json message to web api controller?

Comment: `And this line have never been executed completely (no response)` how do you know? You dont do anything with the response

Comment: In line `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){Thread.Sleep(10);}` i tried to check response code. No result.

Comment: There is no such line in your code. How did you check the response code? `Thread.Sleep(10);` doesn't really do anything in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into a deadlock because of `RunAsync().Wait();`. Your `Test()` Method is blocking the context thread, waiting for `RunAsync()` to complete and `RunAsync()`is waiting for the context to be free so it can complete. This blog from Stephen Cleary describes the problem in detail: [link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The solution would be changing the signature to allow "awaiting" on `RunAsync()`:

`public ActionResult Test()` to `public async Task<ActionResult> Test()`

and

`RunAsync().Wait();` to `await RunAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `fiddler` to find out whether your API works or not.